# my java program is running compiling but not displaying anything

Tags: java

```
package myproj;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import myproj.util.DBUtil;

/**
 *
 * @author PEARL
 */
public class DATAENTRY extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form DATAENTRY
     */
    public DATAENTRY() {
        try {
            initComponents();
            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
            Connection con = util.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from bk_det inner join bk_rep on bk_det.rm_id = bk_rep.rm_id inner join bk_sec on bk_rep.rm_id = bk_sec.rm_id inner join mut_det on bk_sec.rm_id = mut_det.rm_id inner join rm_det on mut_det.rm_id = rm_det.rm_id inner join soil_det on rm_det.rm_id = soil_det.rm_id");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
            Vector columns_name = new Vector();
            Vector data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int i=1; i< columns; i++){
            columns_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
            }
            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);

            while(rs.next()){
            data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int j=1; j< columns; j++){
            data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
            }
            dtm.addRow(data_rows);
            }
            MyTable.setModel(dtm);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
public static void main(String arg[]){

}


}
```

i want to display the records from my sql database to my jtable in netbeans gui but am able to display the compile and running the windows form successfully but it doesnot display the respected form please help

Comment: Learn the Java naming conventions, and stick to them. Also learn to indent your code. It's very hard to read.

Comment: how stupid of me man really thakx mr. Walery Strauch... :-)

Answer (score 4):

This is because you need to call `DATAENTRY()` in the main class

Answer (score 2):

Your main method is empty, so it won't do anything.

```
public static void main(String arg[]){

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that your `main` method is completely empty?  *Everything* in your program happens from `main`.  You would want to instantiate your `DATAENTRY` object from there.

```
DATAENTRY da = new DATAENTRY();
```

It may also be the case that other things break as well; be wary and conscious of any stack traces.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in your main method. Java starts running code from the main method.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
  DATAENTRY de = new DATAENTRY() ;
  de.pack();
  de.setVisible(true)
}
```

Also class name `DATAENTRY` and all the stuff which you've done in constructor is not a proper standard. You should follow java code standards. Google it.

1. Class name can be like `DataEntryFrame`
2. call initialize component after constructing frame like `deFrame.intilizeComponents()`
3. put separate method for updating table content like `fillupTable()`
4. finally call fillupTable method with an event or in main method.